# css format input date 2403//2023 to 24/03/2023

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs3

Now I'm adjusting my css to format input date time, which now it's in this format: 2403//2023. I want it to display like this: 24/03/2023. I've tried to adjust it, but it won't let me. Right between the slash

```
<template>

        <div class="row align-items-center g-3 mt-1">
      <div class="col-md-1 col-12 text-md-end">
            <label class="col-form-label">วันที่</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-12">
            <input
              type="date"
              id="datepicker"
              class="form-control"
              v-model="InputActivityCCTV.dtp_date"
              @change="Change_Date()"
              required
            />
</div>
   </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
input[type="date"]::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 20px 0 4px;
}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-datetime-edit-text {
  background-color: gray;
}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field {
  order: -1;
  background-color: red;
}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field {
  order: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field {
  order: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to fix this in CSS when the data source is clearly providing an incorrect format. Fix it there.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I set the display ui date 24/03/2024

Comment: It's not possible with a native date input, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519493/21232694